# Discord.js - Cannot edit a message

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a problem. Im trying to edit a message and I'm getting an error. How can i fix this?

```
TypeError: polje.edit is not a function
```

My code :

```
    if (msg === "test") {

        let polje = message.channel.send(poljeprazno);

        try {
            var odgovor = await message.channel.awaitMessages(message2 => message2.content === "a1", {
                maxMatches: 1,
                time: 5000,
                errors: ['time']
            });
            if (odgovor.first().content === "a1") {
                if (poljeprazno[0][0] != "⬜") return message.channel.send("Zasedeno");
                poljeprazno[0][0] = "⭕";
                polje.edit(poljeprazno);
            }
        }catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return message.channel.send("Ničesar nisem dobil").then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(5000); });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use `await` when sending the message, and so `polje` is  a `Promise<Message>`, instead of an actual `Message`. You can just write it like this:

```js
let polje = await message.channel.send(poljeprazno)
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Wow you're fast

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

`let polje = message.channel.send(poljeprazno);`

`message.channel.send()` returns a Promise. It's an asynchronous function, so there's no guarantee that when you call `polje.edit(poljeprazno);` that `poleje` even has returned the `Message` object in which the `edit()` function lives.

You want:

`let polje = await message.channel.send(poljeprazno);`